# Magento Magmi image processor errors

Tags: magento, magmi

I have just started using the MAGMI image attribute processor and am having a few issues.

Initially, I was getting open_basedir errors, but I have (I think!!) temporarily disabled open_basedir for the domain.

Now however, I am getting the following:

```
error creating /media/catalog/product/d: 2,mkdir(): No such file or directory
```

for all the images being processed.

My configuration is as follows:

- Server setup is on a Plesk 10 VPS.
- Value for filesystem path in MAGMI: '/httpdocs'
- Image processor local images store: 'media/import/'
- Magmi version 0.7.17

Other posting by dweeves suggest a faulty value for filesystem path, however when I try and enter the full filesystem path into the field (i.e. /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs) this is replaced with simply 'httpdocs' suggesting magmi knows its there already.

Any ideas??

Comment: are there proper permissions set for magmi to create the directory under media/ ?

Comment: yes. Media folder and all subs are 777

Answer (score 2):

If you are running this on a fresh magento install and have never added an image before, the "catalog/product" directory will not exist so you must create it. The image plugin assumes that is there.